# how to know RentalCars api pickup and dropdowntime as it returns the response in 24 bit binary format

Tags: php, joomla

I am making a website for carsearch through api. 
I am telling you how the search is going on. 
firstly, i get the country names using api, after selecting a country, i get city name and then i get pickup location name, from where the car will pick you up. Now using the pick up location_id, i am sending a request to get the response for having the valid "pickup open time response". means at which time, the car is open to pick up.

I am stuck in this point. because, they return a value in 24 bit binary format. I am wondering how to get the exact time from the binary data. They have written some instructions in their documentation, but that is not helping me.

the documentation says---->>>

this is the request--->

```
< PickUpOpenTimeRS>
element PickupOpenTimeRS

diagram <PickUpOpenTimeRS>
<OpenTime/>
</PickUpOpenTimeRS>
```

OpenTime    The binary array containing the open hours array for the specified location on the specified date.

Note:
The OpenTime element will always contain #PCDATA text data of 24 characters long. Each character represents a binary digit specifying if the location is open at that particular time on the specified date.

Example:
this is response->

```
<PickUpOpenTimeRS>
<OpenTime>000000001111101111111000</OpenTime>
</PickUpopenTimeRS>
```

Example Notes:
The example response shows that the specified location is:
Closed between 00:00 to 07:59
Open between 08:00 to 12:59
Closed between 13:00 to 13:59
Open between 14:00 to 20:59
Closed between 21:00 to 23:59

my question is, how we come to know the open time, close time from such a binary digit?

Answer (score 2):

This is easy, consider the array as a string like this

```
 $binary = "000000001111101111111000";
```

Then the location of the digit represents the 24 hour of the day so if you want to check if its open at 8AM.

```
 if ($binary[8] == "1") //is open at 8am.
```

Answer (score 2):

So there are 24 digits representing each hour of the day like so:

```
12AM   2AM   4AM   6AM   8AM   10AM  12PM   2PM   4PM   6PM   8PM   10PM  
  | 1AM | 3AM | 5AM | 7AM | 9AM | 11AM | 1PM | 3PM | 5PM | 7PM | 9PM | 11PM 
  V  |  V  |  V  |  V  |  V  |  V  |   V  |  V  |  V  |  V  |  V  |  V  |
  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  1  1  1   1  0  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  0  0  0
```

So 12 AM is digit 0 and 1 PM is digit 13, etc.

If you want to get the first time it opens I would do it this way:

```
$binary = "000000001111101111111000";
$openingHour = strpos($binary, '1');
echo $openingHour; // result: 8
```

And to get the final close hour you can do:

```
$binary = "000000001111101111111000";
$closingHour = strrpos($binary, '1') + 1;
echo $closingHour; // result: 20
```

Comment: OKay chris and DevZer0 for your enthusiastic help.. Realy Thank you for your answer. :)